# Selenium Python iterate over a table of rows it is stopping at the first row

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am iterating over a table of rows using Selenium Python.  On the GUI i have deleted an item from a table.  In my script I am checking if the item is not there to verify it has been deleted.
When i iterate over my table, it stops at the first row.  It does not continue until to the last row.

E.g. I am passing in a Name parameter to my method.  I would like to iterate the whole table of rows, column 1 and check the Name is not there.  Return true if Name is not there.

My code snippet is:

```
def is_data_objet_deleted(self, name):
    # Params : name : the name of the data object, e.g. Name, Address, Phone, DOB
     try:
        #WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'data_configuration_data_objects_ct_fields_body')))
        table_id = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'data_configuration_data_objects_ct_fields_body')))
        rows = table_id.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")
        for row in rows:
            # Get the columns
            col_name = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[1]  # This is the Checkbox column
            col_name = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[2]  # This is the Name column
            print "col_name.text = "
            print col_name.text
            if (col_name.text != name):
                return True
            #return False
     except NoSuchElementException, e:
        print "Element not found "
        print e
        self.save_screenshot("data_objects_page_saved_details")
        return False
```

My table is stopping at the very first row.
Some help please,
Thanks,
Riaz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just use [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all):

```
def is_data_objet_deleted(self, name):
    table = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'data_configuration_data_objects_ct_fields_body')))
    rows = table_id.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")

    result = all(row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[2].text != name
                 for row in rows)

    # save a screenshot if there was name found
    if not result:
        self.save_screenshot("data_objects_page_saved_details")
    return result
```

Basically, this would return `True` if all the names don't equal to `name` which is in other words: return `True` if `name` is not there.

As a side note, you are handling `NoSuchElementException`, but it would never be thrown by any method used inside the `try` block - `find_elements()` would return an empty list if no elements matching a locator found.

Comment: pythonic, but not very clear for someone new to programming.

Comment: My method save_screenshot is a custom method I have made and it is in my base class.  I have inserted a Try Catch block in save_screenshot.  It should be called shouldn't it?

Comment: Ah find elements returns an empty list if no matching locator is found.  What should I use in my catch block then?

Comment: @RiazLadhani ah, you basically want to make a screenshot if there is name found, right? I would then just assign the result of `all()` to a variable and, if it is True, make a screenshot. And return the variable then.

Answer (score 2):

You're telling it to stop on the first row, if that row doesn't contain the text.

To fix it, change this:

```
for row in rows:
    ...
    if (col_name.text != name):
        return True
```

To this:

```
for row in rows:
    ...
    if (col_name.text == name):
        return False
return True
```

You want to look at every row until you find the item you're looking for. If you find it, the function should return False. If you make it all the way through the loop without returning False, then the item you're looking for is not in the table and you should return True.